# W/System: Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Im very new to android studio. I'm trying to make a signup page with email and password authentication with Firebase. Howerver, whenever I try to click the sign up button it gives:

> W/System: Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null

Can anyone tell me why?

Here is the SignupActivity.java file

```
package com.example.traintrack;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class SignupActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    FirebaseAuth fAuth;
    Button signupBtn;       // Signup Button
    private String userType;
    private TextInputLayout textInputFullName;
    private TextInputLayout textInputEmail;
    private TextInputLayout textInputPassword;
    private boolean submitted = false, validUser = false;
    Spinner spinner;
    public static final Pattern VALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS_REGEX =
            Pattern.compile("^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,6}$", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

    private String email;
    private String password;


    //Validating the signup page
    private boolean validateName(){
        String name = textInputFullName.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();

        if (name.isEmpty()){
            textInputFullName.setError("Field can't be empty");
        } else{
            textInputFullName.setError(null);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
    private boolean validateEmail(){

        String email = textInputEmail.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();

        if (email.isEmpty()){
            textInputEmail.setError("Field can't be empty");
        } else if (!VALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS_REGEX.matcher(email).find()){
            textInputEmail.setError("Please enter a valid email");
        } else {
            textInputEmail.setError(null);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean validatePassword(){
        String password = textInputPassword.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
        if (password.isEmpty()){
            textInputPassword.setError("Field can't be empty");
        } else if (password.length() < 8){
            textInputPassword.setError("Password must have at least 8 characters");
        } else {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    //public void confirm(View button){

    //}



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.signup);

        spinner = findViewById(R.id.signup_type);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.user_types, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        textInputFullName = findViewById(R.id.signup_fullname);
        textInputEmail =  findViewById(R.id.signup_email);
        textInputPassword =  findViewById(R.id.signup_password);
        signupBtn = findViewById(R.id.signup_confirm);


        //Firebase, Sign up by clicking the button
        fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        if (fAuth.getCurrentUser() != null)  // when the current user object is already present
          {
             startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));  //back to main page
             finish();
          }

        //register the user in firebase
        signupBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                password = textInputPassword.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
                email = textInputEmail.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();

                // I have moved the validation here since this is the button for click
                submitted = true;
                if (!validateName() || !validateEmail() || !validatePassword() || !validUser){
                    Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "Cannot create account", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }


                fAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) //successfully created the user
                            {
                            Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "Account created!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            startActivity(new Intent (getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
                            } else {

                            Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "Error !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        });




    }//OnCreated Closing


    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String type = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        if (type.equals(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.user_types)[0]) && submitted){
            TextView errorText = (TextView)spinner.getSelectedView();
            errorText.setError("");
            errorText.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            errorText.setText("Please select a user type");
        } else {
            validUser = true;
            userType = type;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }

}  //Ending
'''
```

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue using wifi on a physical device. But on a device with cell service turned on, I do not see the warning. What happens if you use cell data?

Comment: You can follow this one answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/64657110

Answer (score 28):

Make sure the emulator is connected to the internet. Sometimes the wifi is on but doesnt connect to the internet. This is how i fixed it anyway.

Answer (score 21):

Add this line to manifest.xml inside application tag:

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

Answer (score 16):

Have you enabled the Email/Password Sign-in method on your Firebase console?

[image: Firebase Console]

Answer (score 7):

It worked for me when I wrote a password with more than 6 characters.

So make sure your password is at least 6 characters in length.

Comment: That was the exact solution to my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

**PREPARATION**

1. Check if your emulator has the permission to access internet and also is connected to.
2. Email/Password Sign-in method in your `firebase` console is enabled to gain access.

**STEP 1:** Create sha1 key + debug key information + Adding `firebase`.
You probably have your sha1 key only with the normal information from the release key, I guess?

**STEP 2:** Activate Android Device Verification from `console.cloud.google.com` and insert your sha keys that are automatically generated by `firebase` + their matching preferences (like `package name`...)

**CONCLUSION**

Your code looks good to me! Everything is set up right. I think you forgot some trivial settings or the right sha key.

Comment: How do I check if the emulator has the permission to access internet?

Comment: I installed Network sniffer before and I setup proxy, then I forgot. Thanks for pointing out Step 1

Answer (score 6):

I have this issue only when I use the emulator on Android Studio. I searched and tested a bit and discovered that this problem doesn't appear when I use my own phone to launch my app. Like someone else stated before me it might be because of the wifi connection on the emulator.

(I'm quite new to Android Studio, I'm just sharing the way I solved it, hope it helps)

Use this to use your app on your own device: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device

Answer (score 2):

you can write "it.exception?.printStackTrace()" and you can  know  what is problem.
for example ,I wrote it and  i found the problem, and I knew I hadn't written enough character-

W/System.err: com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthWeakPasswordException: The given password is invalid. [ Password should be at least 6 characters ]

Comment: Hi, where do you write the "it.exception?.printStackTrace()"?
The W/System message just came from my console and I am not sure how to modify the source that log it.

Answer (score 2):

I got that error with an app that I made, and I think the error is the length of the password, because if it is less than six digits, the firebase authentication service will be a submit error, try changing the length!

I come to this conclusion because I print the value of it.exception from the addOnCompleteListener and that told me "Password must be at least 6 characters"

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you don't have that email Id registered in the app.
You can find it in your firebase project users section.
If the Id is there, in the users section.
Delete it and then again run the app now the SignUp should work.
This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by creating a sha1 key with debug key info and adding firebase.

Then I activated "Android Device Verification" from console.cloud.google.com and entered the sha keys that firebase automatically added and added the necessary definitions (package names, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

> constructor one screen to another screen data send so please arrangement is same with one screen constructor to another screen constructor function is always same*

**Another possibility**

> email and password by mistake add little extra space so please add this type user email and password

```
email.toString.trim();
password.toString.trim();
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not getting current user uid from firebase. So, these errors are produced.
You need to check these first:

```
final User user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
final uid = user.uid;
```

Answer (score 1):

please make sure your bluetooth off in your emulator and also your emulator have internet connectivity

Answer (score 0):

I had same error as you. In my case, in the while ,I changed firebase project.
I did clean in android studio and it worked. The google-services.json file generate auto-generated string in android studio. It had to cleaned.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are trying to signup for an account in your firebase auth list, go to `firebase console -> authentication -> users`, then delete the user. Try to sign up with that again (just once, you get this error again if you repeat signup with that user).

Answer (score 0):

What I did was that in the Android Manifest file, make sure that the Java class that connects to the Firebase is declared ***below*** the line where the main activity class is declared.

Answer (score 0):

I was having Same error but using firebase Auth for Email and Password once you delete everything concerning  email and password on  Firebase console.this error seems to creep in  i created a dummy user using add User button and error never went away but i was able to add data to firebase [This user Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqYXM.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had an account with the same email address so I deleted it from "Authentication Users" and from "Database Data" and the problem was fixed!

Answer (score 0):

What solved my problem was that firebase upgraded its latest flutter SDK release to null safety and so also all firebase products like firebase messaging and so on.
So upgrading all my dependencies specially firebase_auth and flutter latest stable SDK release did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing the instantiation of a variable in your main function of your activity. Android studio is very finicky about details. If you declared it as a variable, you need to instantiate it somewhere in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall emulator and try to maintain emulator with play store app

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue I just uninstall the app and install it again and that solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code lines to check out the type of error you have using the `task.getException().getMessage()` method. Either using a toast message or a `System.out.println("Error"+);`

```
mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Success.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                        Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Error"+ task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
```

I got an error message as :

> An internal error has occurred.[API key not valid. Please pass a valid
> API key]

**Solution for this :** Change classpath in project level gradle and sync your project and reinstall.

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem so many times and after a little bit patient of waiting it kinda work **BUT** the console trow me the notification like this :

```
W/System  ( 6027): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.

E/flutter ( 6027): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: setState() called after dispose(): _SignupPageState#633fd(lifecycle state: defunct, not mounted)

E/flutter ( 6027): The preferred solution is to cancel the timer or stop listening to the animation in the dispose() callback. Another solution is to check the "mounted" property of this object before calling setState() to ensure the object is still in the tree.

E/flutter ( 6027): This error might indicate a memory leak if setState() is being called because another object is retaining a reference to 
this State object after it has been removed from the tree. To avoid memory leaks, consider breaking the reference to this object during dispose().
```

so, to counter this error I put additional *if mounted statement* in `the textField` form, like this :

```
TextFormField(
    validator: (val) => val!.isEmpty ? 'Enter Email' : null,
    onChanged: (val) {
       if (mounted) {
           setState(() => email = val);  //the email will trow to String that will give to firebaseAuth
       }
    },
    keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
),
```

if you got the same issue as me in this case, I hope it also works for you...*cheers

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, i was missing Dynamic Links configuration on firebase console

Answer (score 0):

I got this warning:

> Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.

Because I was trying to delete a Firebase auth account after 5 minutes from the authentication. After some digging, I also got a [FirebaseAuthRecentLoginRequiredException](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuthRecentLoginRequiredException) providing this message:

> This operation is sensitive and requires recent authentication. Log in again before retrying this request.

To solve this I have to use [FirebaseUser.reauthenticate(AuthCredential)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser#reauthenticate(com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential)).

Answer (score 0):

Not really solution but just try to wait after pressing button because I was getting this error

```
Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
```

But after I returned from unsuccessfully googling solutions I found this and the user was logged in

[image]