# How to integrate facebook login in flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, facebook-login

I tried to integrate Facebook into my flutter application. Before setting up the login process I first set up the firebase account and Facebook developer account. I also enabled Facebook authentication in firebase and successfully logged in from Facebook by following the guide which was provided by the Facebook developer after the key generation flow. The issue I am facing is whenever I try to authenticate from firebase it always gives me the following error.

```
Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
[firebase_auth/operation-not-allowed] The given sign-in provider is disabled for this Firebase project. Enable it in the Firebase console, under the sign-in method tab of the Auth section. [ The identity provider configuration is not found. ]
```

I don't know what did I missed while integrating with firebase.
[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64727665/w-system-ignoring-header-x-firebase-locale-because-its-value-was-null

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But all the answers mentioned in the suggested link did not work for me. I have enabled email/password verification I have also added the SHA-256 key.