# A sign-in error occurred. com.firebase.ui.auth.data.model.PhoneNumberVerificationRequiredException: Phone number requires verification

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, storage

E/AuthUI: A sign-in error occurred.

com.firebase.ui.auth.data.model.PhoneNumberVerificationRequiredException:
Phone number requires verification. at

com.firebase.ui.auth.ui.phone.PhoneNumberVerificationHandler$1.onCodeSent(PhoneNumberVerificationHandler.java:54) at

com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-
api.zzvf.onCodeSent(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.0.1:1) at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-
api.zzup.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.0.1:1) at
com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth
api.zzut.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.0.1:3) at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808) at
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:101) at
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7529) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245) at
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)

Comment: Please research before posting a new question, this is a similar question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64727665/w-system-ignoring-header-x-firebase-locale-because-its-value-was-null) one

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: Is your `onDataChange` even triggered? What is the location of your database?

Comment: @AlexMamo  No i am using firebase database