# Flutter No Network Security Config specified, using platform default and Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null. Error

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to run and register with Firebase Auth. It doesn't log in, and it gives the console an error like this:

```
D/NetworkSecurityConfig( 1293): No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
W/System  ( 1293): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
```

Login codes:

```
await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
  email: _loginEmail.text,
  password: _loginPassword.text,
);
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64727665/w-system-ignoring-header-x-firebase-locale-because-its-value-was-null

Comment: I have the same problem here.