# "Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale" error with firebase auth in flutter in Android Studio Windows

Tags: flutter, firebase, authentication

I am trying to login and register with email / password in flutter with firebase, despite using a previously written code (with another firebase project) for another project where it worked, now it gives me this problem:

```
W/System  ( 8080): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
I/System.out( 8080): [okhttp]:check permission begin!
I/System.out( 8080): [okhttp]:not MMS!
I/System.out( 8080): [okhttp]:not Email!
I/System.out( 8080): [OkHttp] sendRequest<<
D/FirebaseAuth( 8080): Notifying id token listeners about user ( nF4jLcbGErOidi4SBqTk1wqXNW53 ).
W/org.project_tm( 8080): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->close()V (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
```

I added `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in the application tag in `android > app > main > AndroidManifest.xml` and I'm using my phone, which is connected to internet.

I have been trying to solve this problem for a few days, looking at other questions on the Internet, but have not found any solutions.

Comment: Check all the steps mentioned in this answer. Most likely thing is you forgot to enable auth method in Firebase, or you forgot to add sha1 key in Firebase if you are using google sign in https://stackoverflow.com/a/66993601/10553747

Comment: The account on firebase is created (and also the corresponding document on firestore), so I think the settings are correct, but when I try to log in it loads a bit and then nothing happens. The SHA keys have been entered since I tried to log in with google, but since it didn't work, I decided to use email / password.