# Flutter Firebase Works On Real Device Not On Android Emulator

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, android-emulator

So I'm writing this in case anyone has any ideas. I cannot get Firebase / Firestore working on my Android emulator with my Flutter project.

At this point, all I'm trying to do is sign in anonymously, and check if a document exists by printing something in the terminal to confirm my app has a connection to Firebase / Firestore in a skeleton app.

```
  firebase_auth: ^3.7.0
  cloud_firestore: ^3.4.6
  firebase_core: ^1.21.1
```

Sign in anonymously.

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInAnonymously();

  runApp(const MyApp());
}
...
```

And call this method to tell me if the document exists (it does).

```
Future testFirebase() async {
  await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("fruit")
      .doc("peach")
      .get()
      .then((document) {
    if (document.exists) {
      print("exists");
    } else {
      print("does not exist");
    }
  });
}
```

Doing this causes the app to hang. Then after about 5 minutes, I get a slew of error messages

```
W/System  (13182): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
D/FirebaseAuth(13182): Notifying id token listeners about user ( fUMAwRpjESeaRik9ABkzTNE7bH92 ).
D/FirebaseAuth(13182): Notifying auth state listeners about user ( fUMAwRpjESeaRik9ABkzTNE7bH92 ).
W/DynamiteModule(13182): Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite not found.
I/DynamiteModule(13182): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0
W/ProviderInstaller(13182): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
I/flutterconntes(13182): The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
I/chatty  (13182): uid=10156(com.example.flutterconntest) AsyncTask #1 identical 1 line
I/flutterconntes(13182): The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
D/nativeloader(13182): classloader namespace configured for unbundled product apk. library_path=/product/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/lib/x86:/product/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/PrebuiltGmsCore.apk!/lib/x86:/product/lib:/system/product/lib
W/ProviderInstaller(13182): Failed to report request stats: com.google.android.gms.common.security.ProviderInstallerImpl.reportRequestStats [class android.content.Context, long, long]
W/flutterconntes(13182): Accessing hidden field Ldalvik/system/BaseDexClassLoader;->pathList:Ldalvik/system/DexPathList; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/flutterconntes(13182): Accessing hidden field Ldalvik/system/DexPathList;->nativeLibraryDirectories:Ljava/util/List; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/flutterconntes(13182): Accessing hidden field Ldalvik/system/DexPathList;->systemNativeLibraryDirectories:Ljava/util/List; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/flutterconntes(13182): Accessing hidden field Ldalvik/system/DexPathList;->nativeLibraryPathElements:[Ldalvik/system/DexPathList$NativeLibraryElement; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/flutterconntes(13182): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/DexPathList;->makePathElements(Ljava/util/List;)[Ldalvik/system/DexPathList$NativeLibraryElement; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
V/NativeCrypto(13182): Registering com/google/android/gms/org/conscrypt/NativeCrypto's 286 native methods...
W/flutterconntes(13182): Accessing hidden method Ljava/security/spec/ECParameterSpec;->getCurveName()Ljava/lang/String; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
I/ProviderInstaller(13182): Installed default security provider GmsCore_OpenSSL
I/TetheringManager(13182): registerTetheringEventCallback:com.example.flutterconntest
W/Firestore(13182): (24.2.2) [OnlineStateTracker]: Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Backend didn't respond within 10 seconds
W/Firestore(13182):
W/Firestore(13182): This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.
W/Firestore(13182): (24.2.2) [WatchStream]: (9bc0685) Stream closed with status: Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, description=Channel shutdownNow invoked, cause=null}.
W/DynamiteModule(13182): Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite not found.
I/DynamiteModule(13182): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0
W/ProviderInstaller(13182): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
W/ProviderInstaller(13182): Failed to report request stats: com.google.android.gms.common.security.ProviderInstallerImpl.reportRequestStats [class android.content.Context, long, long]
```

However, on my physical devices running Android Go and Android 12, it works perfectly.

I have:

- Checked Android emulator has Internet connection by opening Chrome / Maps / etc, and they all work fine
- Added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` and `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />` to AndroidManifest main & debug
- Reinstalled Windows
- Reinstalled Flutter, Android SDK, Android Studio, VSCode carefully following a guide to ensure everything is configured correctly
- Set `minSdkVersion 22`
- Tried different apps with different Firebase projects (they all fail on the emulator but work on the real device)
- Tried Flutterfire CLI and manual config
- Created various emulators with various hardware profiles and versions of Android (Play, non Play, various API levels)
- Ensured "Anonymous Signin" is enabled in Firebase
- Set Firestore rules to allow everything if `request.auth != null`
- Checked network settings in Windows to allow Internet access for emulator, but the emulator works fine with all other apps
- Tried with firewall on / off & allowed adb.exe full access
- Changed emulator settings to good signal, full network, charging, plugged in, etc.
- Added `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` to AndroidManifest

And bearing in mind, the physical device works perfectly from from the start without me having to do much of anything. But after reading Stack Overflow for days, I'm at a loss.

If anyone has any ideas that I haven't tried, please do let me know :)
Thanks.

Comment: Does [W/System: Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64727665/10157127) answer your question?

Comment: I've looked at that post and it does not answer my question. Internet does work on my emulator because I use other apps like Chrome fine on it, it's only Firebase that doesn't work on the emulator, but works fine on a physical device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue. Firebase components were working with a huge delay. I had to install earlier emulator version. The problem occured only on my old laptop, my PC was unaffected.

https://developer.android.com/studio/emulator_archive

Comment: It solved the problem. Just to reiterate, I followed Hey's link to the emulator archive, followed the instructions on the page to install an old version of the Android emulator (I installed a version from 1 year ago), then started the emulator + my IDE as normal. Everything works fine now. Thank you so much!