# skip robot verification in firebase phone authorisation using react native

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

While phone verification in firebase, the app opens a App-Name/auth/handler page and does robot verification and returns to app again and then an OTP is recieved.

I want to skip this middle step of robot verification.

I tried using

```
 firebase().auth().settings.appVerificationDisabledForTesting = true;
```

but it seems only for testing purpose and in IOS.

Comment: This is known as a recaptcha, so see some of these results for previous questions about this topic: https://www.google.com/search?q=skip+recaptcha+in+firebase+phone+authorisation+using+react+native

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works on android by registering your application to work correctly with Google's SafetyNet.

Check the documentation on android here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth#enable-app-verification

There has also been a similar question on how to enable SafetyNet in case you struggle: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64657110/3668241

Maybe also of interest:

For iOS to avoid the verification page, you need to enable silent push notification: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth#start-receiving-silent-notifications